# Est-ce que la phrase « excuse-moi des écarts de conduites à ton égard » est correcte?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, formulation

Sinon, quelle serait une autre formule exprimant cette idée? Est-ce que je devrais la repenser et privilégier une phrase plus légère, plus courte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pardonne mes écarts de conduite* est plus court (et évoque l'idée de "pardon" qui est peut-être plus approprié à votre demande).

Comment: Ce que j'entendais par "écart de conduite", c'est que j'ai agi comme un salaud envers ma conjointe, je me suis adressé à elle sur un ton agressif, j'ai tenu des propos qui dépassaient ma pensée et je ne voulais rien entendre. Mais avant toute chose, ce qui m'obsède, c'est le choix de la préposition qu'il convient d'employer après le verbe "excuser" conjugué. Doit-on préférer l'usage de "de" avant un verbe à l'infinitif et "pour" devant un nom, ou bien l'usage recommande d'employer toujours "de" après "excuser", qu'il se trouve devant un verbe à l'infinitif ou non?

Comment: Cela fait un moment que cette question me taraude. Certains ouvrages ne mentionnent pas le tournure avec "pour" avant un nom, tandis que d'autres se contentent de donner un simple exemple, sans toutefois préciser la portée de cet emploi. Par exemple, l'office québécoise de la langue française donne pour exemple "Excuse-moi pour tout à l'heure, [...] et l'Académie française se contente de donner pour seul exemple: "Excuse-moi pour cet oublie". Le Larousse, quant à lui, ne présente aucune phrase dans laquelle "pour" est employé après la conjugaison du verbe "excuser".

Comment: Au contraire de l'Académie française, le Larousse semble laisser entendre, du fait de l'absence de mention de la préposition "pour" dans ses exemples en rapport avec le verbe en question, qu'il convient d'employer en tout temps la préposition "de". Voici un exemple, tiré du  Larousse en ligne, qui vient étayer mes dires: Excusez-moi de mon retard.

Comment: "Pour" n'apparait nul part sur la page traitant du verbe "excuser" dans le Larousse en ligne. Il en va de même pour "Le Robert" en ligne.

Answer (score 1):

Si par *écarts de conduites* vous voulez dire *désobéissance*, *transgression* ou *insubordination*, vous pourriez utiliser ces mots comme *Excuse mes écarts de conduites*, *Excuse ma désobéissance*, ...., votre formulation est un peu lourde.

Normalement, on a besoin de plus d'information comme ce que vous avez faites à la personne pour donner la formulation, mais un simple **Excusez-moi** est suffisant dans la plupart des cas.

Comment: Salut user10191234, j'entendais par là un accès de colère se manifestant dans la façon de s'adresser à une personne, dans le ton employé.

Comment: »Voir commentaires laissés à Greg. Je te remercie pour ta réponse, c'est très apprécié.